# How to approach my MSc advisor that I may want to apply for another PhD program?

Tags: phd, etiquette

I am doing a research-based master's degree at a university, and my advisor was asking me "if I want to do a Ph.D." when I was starting and I said yes. For some reason, he assumed that I'd be doing a PhD under their supervision.

Even though my advisor is an amazing person and I would definitely like to do a Ph.D. with them, there's one single professor in another university that I am also interested in working with. I am still in my first year and I should in theory graduate in two years. How/when can I approach my current advisor that I would also like to apply for another school (alongside my current school)? Especially since I would like them to be one of my references.